# Get the top node/s in a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

I'm trying recursively iterate the entire page. The question is is there a 'TOP' node that all the others are childs are descended from him or is there a series of top level nodes.
And how do I get ONLY the top level node/s?

I noticed that the entire page is a node named "HTML"
[image: nodeName: "HTML"]

So I tried this:

```
document.getElementsByName("HTML")[0]
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: try with document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is...

```
var topNode = document.documentElement;
```

This is the `html` element in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks... It does looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `getElementsByTagName`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0]
```